# wonky behaviour vs2010 get HKLM value even with Run As Administrator c# .NET 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, registry, administrator

For an application that will run as a windows service
I store settings values in a HKLM\Software... registry key.

I've a library that accesses my registry values.

I've a simple test console application that I use to verify that the code works.

To debug via my test console application, I must run vs2010 as administrator.

Everything works:

```
Console.WriteLine(WindowsRegistry.getTaleoOrgCode("test"));
```

invokes

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey hklmLocalMachineRoot =
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey hklmLocalMachineHbsiTaleoClient =
hklmLocalMachineRoot.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Taleo\" + clientName.Trim(), false);
 // read only
if (hklmLocalMachineHbsiTaleoClient != null)
```

via debug, it's clear that hklmLocalMachineHbsiTaleoClient is not null.

I have an application that uses the above library subroutine.

I start that application in vs2010 also as administrator.

via debug, it's clear that hklmLocalMachineHbsiTaleoClient is null.

Before debugging, I ensure that the failing application
has the latest version of my registry routines library.

The vs2010 Pro version is running under Windows 7.

Help, please and thank you.

Comment: Beware registry virtualization on the 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Hans, registry virtualization is a definite possibility. I just looked it up; e.g.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx; in one command window, "reg flags HKLM\Software\... query" works but the same command in both the regular and 64 vs2010 command windows (regardless whether Run as Administrator is used) gets **"ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."**  where the QUERY works, all flags are marked CLEAR but the same command window for SET with/without /s switch gives "ERROR: Access is denied." ???

Comment: wierder still: regedit started from SlickRun showed my keys/values which I exported; regedt32 from Windows\System32 did not show my keys/values until AFTER I imported them; with hope, I reran my test which still can not find the keys/values even though one might assUme that the keys/values should be in both the virtual and non virtual registry. I'm running out of ideas. regardless, Hans my best guess is that these anomalies are definitely related to registry virtualization. thank you for the lead. ttyl P.S.: I can no longer run regedit from SlickRun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans is right in his comment that the demon is registry virtualization.

Please see my follow up queestion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980211/how-do-i-search-all-non-virtual-and-virtual-registries-in-vista-win7-et-cetera

Thank you.